# How to set screen brightness to a particular value? IODisplaySetFloatParameter does not change the screen brightness as expected

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to set the brightness value of macbook using this:

```
    if IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect"), &iterator) == kIOReturnSuccess {
        var service: io_object_t = 1
        while service != 0 {
            service = IOIteratorNext(iterator)
            IODisplaySetFloatParameter(service, 0, kIODisplayBrightnessKey as CFString, level)
            IOObjectRelease(service)
        }
    }
```

However, this does not actually change the intensity of the screen. It just makes the screen whiter (like increasing brightness of picture). Also, the change made using this option reverts back to normal after 5-10 secs.

I can send keypress for `NX_KEYTYPE_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN` and get correct impact on screen brightness but that increases is in discrete steps and not continuous.

How do I achieve the same increase in brightness as I do from preferences programmatically?

I am using Macbook Pro 2019
MacOS Mojave 10.14.6